# kernel methods and parameter updates

Tags: kernel, parameter

Background information:
(it might be helpful to read the first 5 pages of this:https://cs229.stanford.edu/summer2020/cs229-notes3.pdf before answering the question).

I’m currently learning machine learning and one of the sources that I’m using are these lecture notes(https://cs229.stanford.edu/summer2020/cs229-notes3.pdf). The current topic that I'm on is kernel methods. On page 5, the algorithm presented tells you how to update the values of $\beta$. Once you have the values of $\beta$ you can just compute $\theta^{T}\phi(x)$ (as described in equation 12). Everything in this section makes sense except for one thing: the loop in the algorithm on page 5.

The main question is basically when should the loop stop ? Are you supposed to keep on updating the entries of the vector $\beta$ until they seem to converge ?

(Sorry if I'm asking something that may seem obvious)

Thanks